# Maven tomcat7 deploy integration tests failure

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat7, spring-roo

I'm using Spring Tool Suite 3.5.1 to develop a Spring Roo 1.2.5 project. I have generated entities (without Active Record) with **EclipseLink (JPA)**, services (implementations and intefaces) and a simple controller mainly with these commands:

1. database reverse engineer --schema ssigdl --package ~.domain
   --repository --testAutomatically
2. service all --interfacePackage ~.service --classPackage ~.service.impl
3. web mvc setup
4. controller class --class ~.web.CustomPageController --preferredMapping /custompage

Then I try to use maven to deploy with this goal:

- tomcat7:deploy

When the process arrives to the part of tests, it happens these errors

```
Tests in error: 
  testFindEntries(com.ssigdl.sirc.domain.SsiArticuloIntegrationTest): 
(..)
  testFindAll(com.ssigdl.sirc.domain.SsiArticuloIntegrationTest): 
(..)
  testCount(com.ssigdl.sirc.domain.SsiArticuloIntegrationTest): 
(..)
  testFind(com.ssigdl.sirc.domain.SsiArticuloIntegrationTest): 
(..)
  testSave(com.ssigdl.sirc.domain.SsiArticuloIntegrationTest): 
(..)
  testDelete(com.ssigdl.sirc.domain.SsiArticuloIntegrationTest):
```

And a block of errors appear one per entity created. Finally it appears the error message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12:test (default-test) on project sirc: There are test failures.
```

If I set the checkbox **Skip tests** in the Run Configurations Window, the compilation process goes successfully. My problem is:

1. Why the integration tests are failing?
2. Did I have a mistake in the spring roo commands?
3. Does this error affect in some way to my application?

**Update**

This is an image of the error thrown by Spring Tool Suite

[image]

I can't click on the dots

**Solution**

I followed @mvivo instructions and I found that I had this error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'ssigdl.sequence' doesn't exist
```

In this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11671186/jpa-eclipselink-databaseexception-table-foo-sequence-doesnt-exist) I found the answer. Basically the entity has this annotation

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
```

Which combined with MySQL is causing errors, so I used the following annotation instead:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: can you fill in your `(...)` marks with the actual error messages (one or two of them at least)?  It's a bit hard to tell why the test failed, otherwise.

Comment: You aren't going to believe it, but that's exactly what the error throws. Maybe the console hides the error and I don't know how to retrieve the complete error

Comment: if you're in Eclipse (or Spring Tool Suite), usually you can click those ellipses and it will unfold the stack trace or error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get information about test errors open "Navigation" view (menu `Windows > Show views > Navigator`) and look into `target/surefire-reports`. There you can found all outputs of test run.

> Why the integration tests are failing?

Look into *com.ssigdl.sirc.domain.*Test** files. There you'll found all output and stack trace of test execution

> Did I have a mistake in the spring roo commands?

I don't think so. Is possible that you must customize test to adjust to make it run. By example, customize the DOD (Data on demand) service to get coherent data to run test.

> Does this error affect in some way to my application?

If problem (as I suppose to) is that test do something wrong with data, you application can run perfectly if you handle data in the correct way on services.

In my opinion, I advise you to fix the integration test generated by Roo to make it runs.

Think that Roo just generate a *template* for test (and only for CRUD adn find operation) your entity but there is no way to let it know the application logic or especial rules on database tables. This kind of things always are your responsibility (sometimes looks like magic but there is none ;-) )  .