# Unable to persist objects

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, persistence

I am trying to persist an entity using following code

```
public ReservationEntity persistReservation(ReservationRequest reservationRequest) {
    ReservationEntity re = new ReservationEntity();
    re.setTotalPrice(new BigDecimal(123));
    re.setFlightInstance(getFlightInstanceEntity(reservationRequest.getFlightId()));
    List<PassengerEntity> passengers = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Passenger p : reservationRequest.getPassengers()){
        PassengerEntity pe = new PassengerEntity();
        pe.setFirstName(p.getFirstName());
        pe.setLastName(p.getLastName());
        passengers.add(pe);
    }
    re.setPassenger(passengers);

    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(re);
    em.getTransaction().commit();

    return re;
}
```

And the Passenger entity is

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "passenger", schema = "", catalog = "dbname")
 public class PassengerEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator="passengerId")
     private int passengerId;
     private String firstName;
     private String lastName;
 // GETTERS-SETTERS


 }

@Entity
@Table(name = "reservation", schema = "", catalog = "dbname")
public class ReservationEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "reservationId")
    private int reservationId;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name="passengerId")
    private List<PassengerEntity> passenger;
    public void setPassenger(List<PassengerEntity> passenger){this.passenger = passenger;}
    public List<PassengerEntity> getPassenger(){return this.passenger;}
```

I have tried with `GenerationType.AUTO` and with `GenerationType.Sequence` and in both case, either I got an error that `table PassengerEntity.SEQUENCE doesn't exist` ([JPA EclipseLink DatabaseException: 'table foo.SEQUENCE doesn't exist'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11671186/jpa-eclipselink-databaseexception-table-foo-sequence-doesnt-exist))

I tried adding these lines and it actually deleted my entire schema with the data ...

```
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.create-ddl-jdbc-file-name" value="createDDL_ddlGeneration.jdbc"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.drop-ddl-jdbc-file-name" value="dropDDL_ddlGeneration.jdbc"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="both"/>
```

And here is my schema of that specific table. The table has an FK which is having the same problem. I am trying to first persist into parent and then child.

```
CREATE TABLE `passenger`(
    `passengerId` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `firstName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, 
    `LastName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    `reservationId` INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`passengerId`), 
    INDEX `reservationId_idx` (`reservationId` ASC),
    CONSTRAINT `passenger_reservation_reservationId`
        FOREIGN KEY (`reservationId`)
        REFERENCES `reservation`(`reservationId`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

If i change `GenerationType` to `GenerationType.IDENTITY` I get error that

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'reservationId' doesn't have a default value
Error Code: 1364
Call: INSERT INTO dbname.passenger (FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME) VALUES (?, ?)
    bind => [2 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(com.project.entity.PassengerEntity@994)
```

After adding `generator` to the entity and changing type to `SEQUENCE` I am getting same error

```
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'reservationId' doesn't have a default value
```

Comment: Do you have autoincrement on table key?

Comment: Yes, let me update with the schema

Comment: Try GenerationType.IDENTITY. You must set all field which are not null.

Comment: Now I am getting error that **`reservationId` doesn't have default value**. Updating the question as well

Comment: And that's correct. You have to insert reservation first and then insert passenger.

Comment: a SEQUENCE is not an AUTOINCREMENT! Totally different mechanism

Comment: Do you hava autoincrement also on reservationId? Change Sequence to Indentity if you use autoincrement.

Comment: I have tried both. `GeneratorType.Sequence` and `GeneratorType.IDENTITY` ... and i am getting either `default value missing` error or `sequence missing` error. And yes, I have `AUTO_INCREMENT` on both `passenger` and `reservation` tables.

Comment: Do you have not null constraint on ids? Does reservationId is primary key?

Answer (score 0):

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="columnName")
private int passengerId;
```

try annotating your passengerId with above code

Comment: I am getting error that `parentID` doesn't have a default value